# Reference Controller Action from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have ASP.NET MVC actions that return JSON data. My client uses jQuery's `ajax` function to retrieve this data and display it on the screen. I use absolute paths to the controller actions in my JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/Load',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json'
})
```

The problem is that in some environments, we'll add an extra virtual directory to the front, so the URL is actually `/Path/To/App/Home/Load`. I am wondering whether there is a way to write my JavaScript so that it doesn't need updated each time I deploy. I could use relative URLs, like `../Home/Index`, but occasionally I move my JavaScript code around. Things get extra tricky when using MVC's bundler, too. It would be nice if the `~` character worked.

Comment: why dont use `'@Url.Action("action", "controller")'`

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi that will only work if your javascript is embedded in your view which is a bad practice.

Comment: not sure what your url looks like on the page that calls the ajax, but maybe something like `window.location` might give you the base of what you need

Comment: check second answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640559/asp-net-mvc-url-action-in-external-js-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I do:

Add the following lines in your main view (here with the Razor syntax):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var appBaseUrl = "@Url.Content("~")";
</script>
```

Then in Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: appBaseUrl + 'Home/Load',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json'
})
```

Comment: I like this approach. The only downside is that it results in a warning because it inter-mixes razor and JavaScript. I combined both your and @Richard Dalton's approach. `<script id="base-url" type="text/javascript" data-base-url="@Url.Content("~")">var baseUrl = $('#base-url').data('base-url');</script>`

Answer (score 2):

You could put the URL into an element that is relevant to your ajax request:

```
<div id="mydiv" data-url="@Url.Action("Load", "Home")">Click me to load ajax request!</div>
```

Then change your JS code to:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $('mydiv').data('url'), // Could be $(this).data('url') if clicking to load
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json'
})
```

The advantage of this is that it still uses MVCs routing so any custom routes will still work.