# In MVC url is not getting properly on clicking a link for the iis8.5 hosted application

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, iis-8.5

I have a MVC4 application and have hosted on IIS8.5 with published file.
I have a link on my cshtml page

```
<a href='/home/ContactGrabber'>Import Contacts</a>
```

Here home is controller and ContactGrabber is an action of controller. When I am clicking on this link it show 404 error because url is showing

```
http://localhost/home/ContactGrabber
```

It should be

```
http://localhost/cruuntest/home/ContactGrabber
```

But when I am running my development code without hosting on IIS. it works fine.

Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Url.Action` helper for this, so that your url is generated right, by this way you wull face issues:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("ContactGrabber","home")'>Import Contacts</a>
```

you can see details of it on [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505232%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

You can also use `Html.ActionLink` to generate the anchor tag:

## Razor:

```
Html.ActionLink("Import Contacts", 
                "ContactGrabber",   // <-- ActionMethod
                "home",  // <-- Controller Name.
                 null, // <-- Route arguments.
                 null  // <-- htmlArguments .. which are none.
                )
```

[**MSDN docs**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493018%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: yes you are correct but what about in jquery if I am providing var url = "/ContactGrabber/GetData" + location.search; and using $.ajax it also does not work.

Comment: simply this: ``var url = '@Url.Action("GetData","ContactGrabber")'+location;``

Comment: in js file not sure as i never used in seperate js file but in the view it will work

Comment: I have some urls in js also and having this issue.

Comment: for external js files you have to go with this approach:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640559/asp-net-mvc-url-action-in-external-js-file