# Performing a delete in mvc-5 action through JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a website I'm working on, where the user can add or delete booked traffics for a tram network. I've come this far with the delete button.

```
<input type="button" value="Delete" class="deleteTraffic btn btn-link NoBorder NoBackGround" data-id="@traffic.Id" />
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.deleteTraffic').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var url = '@Url.Action("DeleteTraffic", "TrafficDate", new { trafficId=id })';
        url = url.replace("id", id);
        $.post(url, function (data) {
            if (data) {
                $('#pnlEditTraffics').hide().fadeIn('fast');
            } else {
                alert("Error.");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```csharp
public ActionResult DeleteTraffic(int id)
{
    return Json(TrafficData.DeleteTraffic(id));
}
```

the button works fine and the parameter comes through fine, but the Action in the controller is never reached. the controller is named TrafficDateController

Comment: `@Url.Action("DeleteTraffic", "TrafficDate", new { id=id })` The action name comes first, and the parameter name is `id`, not `trafficId`

Comment: Thanks, but that changed nothing. I don't think it properly converts the url string. after debugging and watching url, url is still '@Url.Action("DeleteTraffic", "TrafficDate", new { trafficId=id })' after that line has executed. should it be like that? id has ofc been replaced by a number at that point.

Comment: What is the actual value of `url` in your script? Also, show your routing table

Comment: http://********/TrafficDate/TrafficDate/@Url.Action(%22DeleteTraffic%22,%20%22TrafficDa‌​te%22) and how do I see my route table? I have not fiddled with the route config

Comment: You're calling `Url.Action()` in your `.js`. The server treats `*.js` files as static assets and won't interpret the `Url.Action` call. You need to define the url elsewhere.

Comment: sorry that was the output in the console, not the actual value of url

Comment: See a solution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13641191/1625737

Comment: Thank you! that solved it. I moved the url to be passed along with the id from the button click. now. how do I reload the page without actually leaving the page? when that post is deleted, I would like to refresh the page, is that possible?

Comment: Call `location.reload()` in the callback `function()` you're passing to `$.post(...)`

Comment: Thank you! this solves my problem completely, thank you again! I will mark your answer as a solution even though we solved it here. it got me started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is the order in which you're passing arguments to `Url.Action()`, the *action* name is the first parameter while the second is the controller name:

```
@Url.Action("DeleteTraffic", "TrafficDate")
```

Also, since the `DeleteTraffic` action is meant to be invoked using `POST` verb, you better pass the `id` as part of the request body hence avoiding the need to manually construct the final path using `url.replace('id', id)`:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("DeleteTraffic", "TrafficDate")',
    data = { id: id };

$.post(url, data, function (data) {
     // ...
});
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Action%28System.String,System.String%29)

Comment: I named it params as I already use data there, dunno if that matters tho. but still, the controller action is not called when I press the button, it skips the post completely

Comment: indeed I get a 404 not found

Comment: Does the action decorated with `[HttpPost]`/`[HttpDelete]`,`[HttpGet]`? Is the controller part of an Area?

Comment: the view is named TrafficDate, the controller is named TrafficDateController. do I have to change something in my routeconfig to get this to work?

Comment: the action is not decorated with any attributes yet

Comment: the link in the console looks like this: http://********/TrafficDate/TrafficDate/@Url.Action(%22DeleteTraffic%22,%20%22TrafficDate%22)